# How can I find the exact/complete URL (anchor) for an answer?

Tags: support

Sometimes I want to point someone not only to a similar question but to one special answer. Obviously there exist anchors for answers (and for comments as well) but I fail to see how I can use them without looking at the html-source.

Comment: Related (maybe not a duplicate, as this also covers comments, and that focuses on how to get "long-form" links): [How to obtain a direct link to an answer?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/4075/how-to-obtain-a-direct-link-to-an-answer)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For questions and answers, you need to click the share link that comes up below them.

[image]

For comments, there is a timestamp next to the comment. When you right click on it, you can copy the link.

[image]

Comment: Oh the joys of naming :-) I do know that behind "share" often a link is to be found, but obviously my brain is (after having seen thousands of "SHARE this with your friends" suggestions) determined not to see the word "share" any more. I never noticed that there is something on the left of "edit".

Comment: @guntbert: Then I would also suggest you to look at the right side of the site - it contains other related questions (very often helpful) & Community Bulletin (update of what's happening with AU and SO in general) - atleast I didn't notice them earlier until I was referred about it :-)

Comment: @Aditya I already learned that by getting good answers to another question I asked here :-)